# Coffeescript compile error

Tags: coffeescript

i just installed Coffeescript and tried a test compile but it always drop me errors for silly things, Coffeescript only compile correctly when only Coffeescript syntax is used?

because if yes then i understand the error.[image]

concDev.js contents:

```
/*! ProjectName 2013-08-18 06:08:39 */
$(function() {

  // Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
  (function() {
      var method;
      var noop = function () {};
      var methods = [
          'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
          'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
          'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
          'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
      ];
      var length = methods.length;
      var console = (window.console = window.console || {});

      while (length--) {
          method = methods[length];

          // Only stub undefined methods.
          if (!console[method]) {
              console[method] = noop;
          }
      }
  }());

});
// New file
$(function() {

  // Handler for .ready() called.

});
```

Comment: Well, yes, a CoffeeScript compiler only compiles CoffeeScript. Could you show the code you've tried to compile? (And please copy-paste the error messages as text, not as a screen capture.)

Comment: I edited my former post, but i guess @Juhanna you are right, it is like in sass, you cant mix regular css syntax with sass/scss syntax right?

Comment: Basically yes. The compiler can't know which part is JS and which part is CS. Why would you want to compile a JavaScript file anyway?

Comment: @EgyedAttila if you want to mix in straight javascript into coffeescript you can embed the js by using ` ` around the expression.  But it sort of escapes the point of using coffee to begin with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use C style comments in Coffeescript.

This

```
/*! Project Name ...*/
```

should be this

```
# Project Name ...
```

More generally, if you're using the Coffeescript compiler, you need valid coffeescript syntax and can't mix and match JS and coffeescript files.

### Update

You're trying to pass a JS file to a coffeescript compiler.  The coffee compiler accepts a coffeescript file, and compiles it to a JS file.  Your file in Coffeescript would look something like this:

```
#! ProjectName 2013-08-18 06:08:39 */
$ ->

  # Avoid `console` errors in browsers that lack a console.
  do  ->
      noop = -> null
      methods = [
          'assert', 'clear', 'count', 'debug', 'dir', 'dirxml', 'error',
          'exception', 'group', 'groupCollapsed', 'groupEnd', 'info', 'log',
          'markTimeline', 'profile', 'profileEnd', 'table', 'time', 'timeEnd',
          'timeStamp', 'trace', 'warn'
      ]
      length = methods.length
      console = window.console = window.console || {}

      while length--
          method = methods[length]
          # Only stub undefined methods.
          if !console[method]
              console[method] = noop;
// New file
$ ->
  #Handler for .ready() called.
```

If you really need to have some JS in your coffeescript file, you can embed it using backticks like this

```
a = `(function() x{ return 2;})()`
```

Comment: thanks, but if i delete the first line it will drop an error for the function syntax

Comment: Well thats because there is more than one error :) You're trying to compile a javascript file with a coffeescript compiler.  Coffeescript compilers compile javascript to coffeescript.  They will throw lots of errors on that file since plain javascript is not valid coffeescript syntax.